# Version Parse in .NEt 3.5

Tags: c#, parsing, .net-3.5

i have this code:

```
version = Version.Parse(node["version"].InnerText);
```

In (node["version"].InnerText) i have "1.3.8.1"

I don´t know, how i do this in .NET 3.5. 
I must use .NET 3.5, not 4.
Have you any ideas please?

Comment: You get any exception or error message? Looks like `Version.Parse` method added with .NET 4.0 version. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26581572/how-to-convert-string-into-version-in-net-3-5

Comment: Error:'System.Version' does not contain a definition for 'Parse'

Comment: Yes i Know, but i need this in .NET 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Version.Parse` has been added in .NET 4.0.

For .NET 3.5 you can use the [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0hf9t2e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), i.e.

```
var version = new Version(node["version"].InnerText);
```

or

```
version = new Version(Node["version"].InnerText);
```